# DATATABLE jQuery TH and TD alignment

Tags: jquery, datatable

hi guys I have a code using jquery.datatable

I want the header to be center align and the td to be right aligned, 
 for example  and

my code js

```
var myegiftcardstable = $j('#myegiftcardstable').dataTable(
            {
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo $this->getUrl('myegiftcard/egiftcard/getMyEGiftCards') ?>",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable"  : true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "prod_name"},
                        { "sName": "egiftcard_code" },
                        { "sName": "price" ,"sClass": "a-right"},
                        { "sName": "is_redeemed" , 'bSortable' : false},
                        { "sName": "date_redeemed", "sClass": "width_120 " },
                        { "sName": "action",'bSortable' : false }
                ],
            }
        );
```

do you have any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this response is a year late, but I did find an answer that works for me.

```
var myegiftcardstable = $j('#myegiftcardstable').dataTable(
            {
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo $this->getUrl('myegiftcard/egiftcard/getMyEGiftCards') ?>",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable"  : true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumns": [
                        // Column index begins at 0
                        { "sClass": "a-right", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                        { "sClass": "width_120", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
                ],
            }
        );
```

Here is the documentation on usage.

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Comment: That won't centre the header though will it?

Comment: @kristianp if not you can use some easy css like .cntrth3 tbody tr th:nth-child(3) { text-align:center; } where 3 can be changed for whatever th you want to center, then just add the class to the table.  I usually have classes like this for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Styling should be done using css :

```
#myegiftcardstable th { text-align: center }
#myegiftcardstable td { text-align: right }
```

Comment: It won't work like that, because datatables puts the th's and td's in different tables and treats them like td's; while also using a lot of inline styling. I've managed to center text in two ways with datatables: eitehr figure out what the correct css selector is and use CSS (you might have to use !Important); or put your th/td content in a 100% width span and center it inside the span.

Comment: could you elaborate on that ? You seem to describe the behavior of some fixed header plugin, which the OP doesn't mention. Plus he safely deactivated the "bAutoWidth" option.

Comment: I've used [OP's specific plugin](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html) in the past. If you check the table after DataTables has been applied to it, you'll see that it's wraped in several layers of div/tables and the original table you had on the page isn't there anymore. Datatables also uses inline styles to define every layout option, and doesn't play nice with any change you want to bring to it. Centering text should work though, if you find the correct CSS selector for it.

Comment: In the example you linked, the original table is still there, and the wrapping is pretty minimal. True, as a default behavior, dataTable wraps the table in div nodes, mainly to add extra fileds (filtering, page counts, etc...), it also alters the existing table (you can see classes added to rows, the "dataTable" class added to the table), and if you don't specify "bAutoWidth", it applies some hocus pocus magic to compute a "desired" width to columns, but the original table node is still there (and still has its original id). Does your comment apply to this use case ?

Comment: Given the amount of settings this plugin has, I can't say that this scenario has the exact same settings as when I used it. So if the impact is minimal, your solution should work. I just wanted to note that the HTML structure could very well be very different if someone ever alters the Datatable's settings.